# Jasper - first page in blank

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm inserting a table in my detail band, but if the value is too long in my textfield, the value is showed only in the second page and because of this the first page is blank.

How I can avoid empty first page on Ireport?

Below is my XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RelatorioLicenca" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="089efa24-5b40-467a-b66a-053b77756f0c">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="dataset1" uuid="7664203f-829d-4951-8151-f0c3630108d3"/>
    <subDataset name="dataset2" uuid="b05d44f7-3dfe-4fb8-9014-34c037e8bc28"/>
    <subDataset name="dataset3" uuid="f3336d08-b905-45da-9cd2-871a08fbb704"/>
    <subDataset name="dataset4" uuid="8a31051f-53a0-4438-8f36-655294512ecb"/>
    <subDataset name="itemDataSet" uuid="07d68903-44a5-4148-9f4e-46a764459558">
        <field name="html" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="LOGO_IMAGE" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
    <parameter name="BARRA_IMAGE" class="java.io.InputStream"/>
    <parameter name="listCriterioQci" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="73" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="137" y="2" width="284" height="54" uuid="07b821b9-797c-439c-92e8-1963c63ee2ae"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{LOGO_IMAGE}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="59" width="555" height="14" uuid="4b071978-b491-4bdb-b964-77cc3e378966"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{BARRA_IMAGE}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="218" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="table" positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="2" y="8" width="553" height="197" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="086200b3-e8f8-454d-84ef-d91dbe233d92"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="itemDataSet" uuid="376ddebe-37e7-49e4-9a3c-c12cdb054808">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{listCriterioQci}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="554" uuid="cc022176-90eb-4639-8818-85293cb2da05">
                        <jr:detailCell style="table" height="135" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="31" width="554" height="92" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="75438790-5295-4508-b6fe-cae1b962ae1d"/>
                                <box>
                                    <pen lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    <topPen lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    <leftPen lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                    <rightPen lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement markup="html"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{html}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <line>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="15" width="554" height="1" uuid="7a8ae78a-41c3-4612-aeff-4aa9bbfe74f5">
                                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($F{html} != null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                                </reportElement>
                            </line>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="342" y="4" width="170" height="13" uuid="26decbd6-15dd-4f66-99d7-132b5b54a889"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="514" y="4" width="40" height="13" uuid="e34184f8-e277-4ec3-9a69-0c07d0729e25"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="1" y="4" width="211" height="13" uuid="68ea646b-0cef-4427-86b7-32f0f5bd47f8"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="5" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Try changing the `positionType` to `Absolute` for the elements in `Detail` band.

Comment: @Viki888 in positionType I haven't option 'Absolute', only float, fix relative to top and fix relative to bottom, and none resolved my problem.